# ¿Cómo llenar un DataGridView con una función y mandarlos a otra tabla?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, stored-procedure, datagridview

Estoy intentando llenar un DataGridView con una función pero hasta ahora no me muestra nada no se que tenga mal

Este es el código que utilizo:

```html
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("buscar", conexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                tbladetalle.DataSource = dt;
```

Así es como tengo la función

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.buscar()
    RETURNS TABLE(codigo integer, cliente character varying, proveedor character varying, total integer, fecha timestamp without time zone, codigod integer, producto character varying, cantidad integer, precio integer, subtotal integer) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$    
BEGIN
 return query SELECT f.codigo,f.cliente,f.proveedor,f.total,f.fecha,d.codigod,d.producto,d.cantidad,d.precio,d.subtotal FROM factura f
                INNER JOIN detalle d ON f.codigo = d.codigo;
           --   WHERE f.codigo = d.codigo  ;                                                       
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Si ejecutas unicamente el `select` en la Base de Datos, te muestra los resultados?

Comment: si, en la Base de Datos me los muestra

Comment: Si dices que la función en la base de datos te muestra los datos, tu código C# parece estar bien, intenta cambiar esto: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` por esto `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: nada,sigue sin mostrarme los datos

Comment: Puedes verificar en el Debug, cuando ejecutas `da.Fill(dt);` que contiene tu `dt` ?

Comment: no muestar nada

Comment: mmm, entonces donde abres la conexión?, muestra alguna advertencia u error al ejecutar??

Comment: no, tampoco me muestra error ni nada

Comment: Solo dices no funciona, pero no proporcionas muchos detalles para saber el por qué, [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ya lo soluciones borre todo y lo empece de nuevo, de todas formas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, el principal problema es que el datasource que crear nunca lo estás llenando con la información para que se llene tu DGV, modifica tu código de esta manera para que funcione:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("buscar", conexion);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
tbladetalle.DataSource = da;
```

Me cuentas como te va.

Comment: si, ya lo solucione gracias

Comment: Excelente @Carlos, por favor publica tu respuesta o selecciona la indicada y marcala como correcta para poder cerrar adecuadamente tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero que pueda ayudarte, y si añades lo siguiente a tu código:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("buscar", conexion);
                NpgsqlDataReader lect = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                tbladetalle.DataSource = dt;
                lect.Close();
```

Comment: tampoco me ha funcionado

Comment: y como tienes la conexión?

Comment: la conexion la tengo asi  NpgsqlConnection conexion = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5433; User Id=postgres;Password=pasword;Database =factura");

Comment: Intenta abrir la conexion como esta en este link: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand/-/php-npgsqlcommand-class-examples.html    LINEA 66 para abrir y LINEA 81 para cerrar

Comment: asi tambien lo he intentado pero no me funciona

Comment: ya lo solucione, solo lo borre todo y lo hice de nuevo, de todas formas gracias